# Magento 2: How to override Ui & Component folder files

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, adminhtml, overrides, catalog

How to override these below files:

1. `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/ConfigurablePanel.php`
2. `vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form.php`

`ConfigurablePanel.php` is defined in vendor/magento/module-ui/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom module, `app/code/Module/Namespace/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Ui\Component\Form" type="Module\Namespace\Component\Ui\Form" />
</config>
```

Then place the `Form.php` in  `Module\Namespace\Component\Ui\`  path.

Then in that file rewrite,

```
namespace Module\Namespace\Component\Ui;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;

/**
 * Class Form
 */

class Form extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Form
{

    public function getDataSourceData()
    {
          #your code
    }

}
```

Comment: I did that mentioned but not succeed . https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187908/magento-2-override-releted-php-class-file-under-ui-dataprovider-folder#187908

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to rewrite it as a preference inside a di.xml?

```
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ConfigurablePanel" type="Custom\Module\Some\Class" />
```

If you need more info about di.xml based dependancy injection
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html
http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/01/22/preferences-in-magento-2/

Otherwise, please provide more information