# Magento 2: How to override Related.php class file under Ui/DataProvider folder?

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, uicomponent

I just want to rewrite `modifyMeta` method on `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php` file and I have done following things in file but not succeeded.

I have followed the [Magento 2: How to override Ui & Component folder files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171434/magento-2-how-to-override-ui-component-folder-files) answer, but unable to rewrite the method.

Here steps what I did:

1. `app/code/Custom/Modulename/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related" type="Custom\Modulename\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related"/>
</config>
```

2. `app/code/Custom/Modulename/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php`

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Modulename\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class Related extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related
{
    
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    { 
       echo "In overrided class " , get_class($this);
       die;
    }
}
```

**Note: I am using Magento 2 Enterprise Editions 2.1.7**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you give a try using a plugin as you are trying to override a public function instead of using a preference?

Comment: No. Let me try with that.

Comment: @Nikolas : did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have overridden `modifyMeta` method by using `virtualType` tag in `adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="logotype" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Custom\Modulename\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Comment: Any idea on this. I have also getting override issue.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365278/magento-2-facing-error-to-override-dataprovider