# How to remove ''Attribute' section block in magento 2 backend (admin page) add new product page?

Tags: admin, magento2.2, product-attribute

Using magento 2.2, in admin page. I want to add new product **without** using **Attribute** . So how to remove this block?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Override `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Attributes` in your custom module, you can take reference from [Magento 2 : Override Releted.php class file under Ui DataProvider folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187908/magento-2-override-releted-php-class-file-under-ui-dataprovider-folder)

And replace below code

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    if (!$this->canAddAttributes()) {
        return $meta;
    }

    if (isset($meta[static::GROUP_CODE])) {
        $meta[static::GROUP_CODE]['arguments']['data']['config']['component'] =
            'Magento_Catalog/js/components/attributes-fieldset';
    }

    $meta = $this->customizeAddAttributeModal($meta);
    $meta = $this->customizeCreateAttributeModal($meta);
    $meta = $this->customizeAttributesGrid($meta);

    return $meta;
}
```

with

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    return $meta;
}
```

Also replace below code

```
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    return $data;
}
```

with

```
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me by SQL?