# Magento2: Remove Sample field from Downloadable Information

Tags: admin, magento-2.2.5, downloadable

I want to remove sample field from downloadable information as highlighted in image below:
[image]
Can anyone give me solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify below file:

```
/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Samples.php
```

line no : 102

```
 public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    => 'label' => __('Samples'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can override File :-

```
/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Samples.php
```

How to Override File :-

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187908/magento-2-override-releted-php-class-file-under-ui-dataprovider-folder)